# VS Code is showing unable to import pyperclip module

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, module, python-import

I've installed pyperclip module by using:

```
pip3 install pyperclip
```

My default version of python is 3.6.6.
Well my program is running fine in terminal and IDLE too. But VS code is showing red and green curly lines and stating errors. See images:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem with another library. I fixed it with:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in VS Code
2. Search `Python`: Select Interpreter
3. Choose one of the options (If you have multiple environments, select the one where the library is installed)

For additional info, check https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-an-environment

Answer (score -1):

Just open a new powershell tab in your VS code and type the following command (you can refer to the screenshot added as well):
**pip install pyperclip**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imyDP.png)